# Custom button or bookmarklet to toggle Conversation View On/Off

Tags: gmail, javascript, customization

I'm trying to write a script that will add a button (or even use a bookmarklet) to toggle Conversation View on and off.

This works, some of the time, to do the toggling:

```
window.location.href = "https://mail.google.com"+window.location.pathname+"#settings/general";
setTimeout(function() {
    convTogs = document.getElementsByName("bx_vmb");
        if (convTogs[0].checked) convTogs[1].click(); 
        else convTogs[0].click();
        document.querySelector("[guidedhelpid=save_changes_button]").click();
}, 5000);
```

This adds the button where I want it:

```
var btn = document.createElement("div");
btn.id = "cvtoggle";
btn.classList.add("G-Ni","J-J5-Ji");
btn.innerHTML = "ConversationView";
btn.setAttribute("onclick", _____code____);
document.getElementsByClassName("Cr aqJ")[0].prepend(btn)
```

but whatever `___code___` I use, I get an error in console:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-30MWHJuxRebUkp5KrawUmw' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Also, the method of going to Settings is poor; it causes a full refresh.

The selector for the "Setting" link in the gear menu is
`document.querySelector('#ms > div')`
but I can't figure out how to "click" it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In order to toggle the conversation view your code should use the Gmail API which could imply the use of OAuth.</strike>

It looks that the only way to toggle the conversation view setting is through the Gmail Settings web page.

There is no way to avoid a full refresh as the setting affects how Google serves the Gmail's client-side code.

One alternative is to build your own email message list by using the Gmail API.

Reference
https://developers.google.com/gmail

Comment: Are you referring just to the action of going to the settings page? The toggling works, mostly, via the above javascript. \\ Is there a way to use the Gmail API from within my actual Gmail page?

Comment: Also, I don't even see an option to change the view over at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

Comment: @Ze'ev I'm sorry, I assumed that https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings included it, but it did't.